# Why are contents of a binary file not being printed in c?

Tags: c

Hello I am writing a program that reads the contents of a binary file and prints them to the screen.

```
  #include <stdio.h> 
 #include <stdlib.h> // For exit() 

 int main() 
 { 
FILE *fptr; 

char filename[100];


printf("Enter the filename to open \n"); 
scanf("%s", filename); 

// Open file 
fptr = fopen(filename, "rb"); 
if (fptr == NULL) 
{ 
    printf("Cannot open file \n"); 
    exit(0); 
} 

// Read contents from file
fseek(fptr,0L,SEEK_END); 
int fsize = ftell(fptr);
fseek(fptr,0L,SEEK_SET); 
unsigned char  *c = malloc(fsize);
fread(c,fsize,1,fptr); 
fclose(fptr); 
printf("%s",c);

return 0; 
}
```

but it does not print anything.Can someone explain me why and how should I fix this problem.

Comment: You will end up printing unprintable characters. Some of these characters have a side effect. Cast each character to an unsigned int and print it in hex format.

Comment: @kaylum You are right. I mistakenly assumed that the element size was one. (1 byte per character element and n characters). This would be more in line with the signature of fread. Deleted my remark. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have attempted is not at all what you wanted to achieve.

Remember `printf()` *formats* the data it *prints*. To be printed properly with the `%s` formatting, the binary data values must be *ASCII values* but , of course, they are **not**.

You should probably attempt to `printf()`  with `%d`.

Comment: Thanks mate.Just made a for loop and printed them with %x as I wanted the hex values.

Comment: Your welcome, Atharva. Do remember that `%o` and `%x` formatted data is formatted as **unsigned** octal and hex, respectively. Also, If my answer helped guide you, please upvote !